# I have installed gtk 2.0 then i compiled my code then it donot find gtk.h?

Tags: c, ubuntu, linker, gtk

i typed following commands on ubuntu

```
sudo apt get-install gtk+2.0
gcc x.c
```

it gives error

```
x.c:1:21: fatal error: gtk/gtk.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
```

this is x.c

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

  GtkWidget *window;

  gtk_init(&argc, &argv);

  window = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
  gtk_widget_show(window);

  g_signal_connect(window, "destroy",
      G_CALLBACK(gtk_main_quit), NULL);  

  gtk_main();

  return 0;
}
```

**I just compile it again
gcc -o simple x.c pkg-config --libs --cflags gtk+-2.0 but can anybody tell me why it runs**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The compiler needs to know where to find the include files and the libraries for GTK.  If you run

```
pkg-config --libs --cflags gtk+-2.0
```

you will find out the extra options that you need to add to your `gcc` command in order for it to find where `gtk.h` is and what libraries your binary needs to be linked with.

Running something like

```
gcc -o simple x.c $(pkg-config --libs --cflags gtk+-2.0)
```

will give `gcc` the information it needs.

Comment: ok what if i want to take it is as default one i mean I want to run only gcc x.c and it will run properly is there any method

Comment: Why the downvote? The answer seems correct to me.